# How to setup gitlab pipeline for android deployment with fastlane

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy, gitlab

I am setting up the GitLab pipeline for building and deploying Android app to the store.
I am following the official GitLab instructions from [here](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/06/13/android-cicd-with-gitlab/) and have encountered a problem with setting up Gradle Config from the instructions.

In instruction, it says to do the following:

***Configure Gradle***

*Next, configure Gradle to use the newly created keystore. In the app/build.gradle file, add the following:*

*Right after the plugins section, add:*

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('release-keystore.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

*Before Build Types, add:*

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
     keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
     keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
     storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
     storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
```

*Lastly, add the signingConfig to the release build type:*

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

My problem here is that instructions are written for Groovy Gradle, and I am using the Kotlin version. I can not find any example of how to migrate things like this from Groovy to Kotlin.